# Any other ways to convert a timestamp in string format to numerical millisecond format?

Tags: javascript, performance, date, date-conversion

Besides:

`Date.parse(timestampString)`

and

`new Date(timestampString).getTime()`

???

I am running some benchmarks, and trying to find the fastest/most efficient way to convert a timestamp like `'2021-08-07 03:32:05.387089'` to `1628321525387`.

Comment: Your biggest issue is using the built–in parser, see  [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) Writing your own parse function will likely be faster than using a library.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr new Date().valueOf()

There is another option:
`new Date(timestampString).valueOf()`

[Here you have benchmark valueOf() vs getTime()](https://perf.link/#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%3D)

Comment: `+new Date()` is faster, but the issue here is using the built–in parser for an unsupported format is flawed in the first place. A robust parse will take very much longer than the conversion to number, so the OP is focusing on the wrong issue.